# Reason for The local variable may not have been initialized?

Tags: java

This is what my method looks like

```
public int abc()
{
  int x;
  if(x > 100)
  {
    //Say ok
    return x;//Causes compiler error
  }

  //if something more, x = some number 

  return x;//Causes compiler error


}
```

I saw an answer at SO - [Java: "Local variable may not have been initialized" not intelligent enough?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12661417/java-local-variable-may-not-have-been-initialized-not-intelligent-enough)

But, I am still not sure why this error happens. Its a compiler error and not a warning. So, the problem must be something more serious than "taking a safe route".

Comment: Look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/415687/why-are-local-variables-not-initialized-in-java

Comment: The compiler is not smart enough to solve for the condition. It will only check that all paths to where the variable is read contains an initial write.

Comment: well even if if condition is true its not intializing anywhere

Comment: try 'int x = 100 ;' then have a look at the logic - all that is happening is x is being returned. Maybe you want to pass in x as parameter.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Local variables must be initialized before they are accessed. This is why there is a compiler error.

You should must have an error at the `if` statement where it's first accessed.